# How to open a drawer when the application starts?

Tags: flutter

My app load on started page, and when my page is loaded me need automacly show drawer menu, how can I open this? in `void main()`, have this:

```
new MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/page',
      builder: (context, widget) {

        return new Padding(
          child: widget,
          padding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: AppPage()));

class AppPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppPageState createState() => _AppPageState();
}

class _AppPageState extends State<AppPage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.run(() => _key.currentState.openDrawer());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: Drawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    /* 
    This is a method from the dart:async library that schedules a callback function to be executed after a specified duration. It runs the provided callback function after a certain delay.
     */
    Timer.run(() => _key.currentState!.openDrawer());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      appBar: AppBar(),
      drawer: const Drawer(),
    );
  }
}

    enter code here
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**